# Plesk / Dr. Web: "The filter fails to pass object to the DrWEB daemon"

Tags: anti-virus, email

I've been trying to figure this one out all day long, so every comment would be highly appreciated!

I have a Plesk webserver and installed Dr. Web (with a proper licence). Everything seems to be working fine, only some (meaning not all but still hundrets a day) emails get rejected becuase Dr. Web causes an error.

The email I get looks something like this:

> Dear Postmaster,
>
> the message with following attributes has not been delivered,
>   because contains an object which cannot be checked by antivirus.
>
> Sender = a@bc.de
>
> Recipients = b@bc.de
>
> Subject =  The Subject
>
> Message-ID = CBEPIDEIGGBBNIJCDKKLEEJPCJAA.xxx@xxx.de
>
> --- Dr.Web report ---
>
> Dr.Web detailed report:
>   The filter fails to pass object to the DrWEB daemon
>
> --- Dr.Web report ---

Can anybody make sense of this error?

> The filter fails to pass object to the DrWEB daemon

Answer (score 1):

Check for any filtering is applied in Dr Web which is rejecting the mail.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, can you clarify?

Comment: I believe the problem is not the filtering, it's that the filter can't event be applied because of an error...

Answer (score 1):

Chage the configuration file like below.
`/etc/drweb/drweb_qmail.conf`

```
ScanningErrors = pass
ProcessingErrors = pass
```